# Custom keyboard on flutter page

Tags: flutter, dart

Currenly I have a small game with the user inputing 3 numbers. But now I was thinking in including a custom keyboard for that.

I've done the keyboard, but can't manage to add it on the page.
I was using

```
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: controller,
                    maxLength: 3,
                    maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.enforced,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),
                    ],
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: '',
                      counterText: '',
                    ),
                    style: const TextStyle(color: bgColor),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => onSubmitted(controller.text),
                    child: const Text('Confirm'),
                  ),
```

and my keyboards looks something like this

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .70,
              child: Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Table(
                    children: [
                      TableRow(children: [
                        buildButton("C", 1, Colors.black),
                        buildButton("7", 1, Colors.black),
                        buildButton("8", 1, Colors.black),
                        buildButton("9", 1, Colors.black),
```

Is this the best way to do something like that or should i go for other plans?

Answer (score 0):

try create keyboard from some button, when button tapped will be your number